# Looping through for-loop to get the string

Tags: java, for-loop

I was having a problem when trying to loop thru a for loop. What I am trying to do is I got a list to store a list of foods. Then, I let user select if (1) then fast food else (2) then japanese food. After that I am trying to set the foodType:

```
 int foodOption;
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 List<String> foodList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("KFC", "Sushi"));
 foodOption = sc.nextInt();
 for (int j = 0; j < foodList.size(); j++) {
     if (j == foodOption) {
         foodType = foodList.get(j);
         System.out.println("Testing;" + foodType);
     }
 }
```

However, when I try to print out foodType, it does not show anything. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please, provide out-put what exactly want in against to input

Comment: What is sc and what is foodOption? Please add them to the code.

Comment: sc is Scanner. foodOption is int

Comment: Please provide [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you only actually want to do something for `f == foodOption`, you don't need a loop: simply `foodType = foodList.get(foodOption);`

Comment: Do you have **another** `sc.nextInt()` prior in your code?

Comment: This seems to be a homework question, but does not conform to [the SO policies for such questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). You have not posted any evidence of a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well this all depends on what you are inputting. Don't forget that arrays will start at index `0` meaning if you put in anything greater than `1` You won't get any output.

In your `List<String> foodList` you have two elements; These are located at point `0 = KFC` and point `1 = Sushi`.

When you do the `if( j == foodOption )` if the user has not entered `0` or `1` then you will never see output as it does not exist in the `List`

Answer (score 0):

Array and list indexes are zero-based. You list is of size 2, which means that the largest index it has is 1. That is why you don't see any output when `foidOption` is 2. When you enter 1, you should be getting "Sushi" in the output.

Note also, that the loop is completely unnecessary. You can remove it, and just do `if(foodOption < list.size) foodType = foodList.get(foodOption)` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Add type `<String>` to your ArrayList declaration.

```
List<String> foodList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("KFC", "Sushi"));
```

Also, the ArrayList has index starting at 0.  So, entering '2' as your `Scanner` input is not going to return a value because it's outside the array index (0 = 'KFC', 1 = 'Sushi').

Comment: The declaration is fine.

Comment: Apologies, I'm running JDK 1.6, in which it throws a compilation error.

Comment: jdk 1.6 is a pig ... and has reached the "end-of-life" three years ago. Don't mislead people by basing your answers on what it tells you.